# Confused in how to print an array hellically

Tags: c, arrays

I have been trying to figure out how can we print a array hellically but i am stuck on how to get started.Any algorithms or ideas will be very helpful.Thanks
**HELLICALLY** means printing the array in concentric circular shape

Comment: What do you mean by "hellically?" I'm not familiar with that term.

Comment: A 1-D array? That's interesting.

Comment: Can you use curses or similar?

Comment: @nathon :anything can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting what you're saying correctly, you want to print the contents of an array, but in a spiral.

I would start by allocating a big rectangular block of memory (a 2-D array) and initializing it to zero. This represents the screen. Then devise a function for determining the coordinates of the next point in the circle and make some coordinate variables initialized to the origin point. Fill the screen by dropping array members wherever they go.

Print out the screen-array, one row at a time, but substitute space for zero.

Screen size and next-coordinate-function are left as exercises for the reader.

Comment: This should work for concentric circles too. The next-coordinates function just has to draw circles instead of a spiral. It might be easiest to do this in polar coordinates (r, theta) and pass those to another conversion function to get your 2-D array coordinates.

Comment: The easiest way to map a circle onto a 2D array is the Midpoint Circle Algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm